# Structuring XML using FOR XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, for-xml

I am trying to return XML using `FOR XML` from a SQL query, and I'm almost there, except it seems like I can't get it to the exact format I need it.

Here is the statement I constructed so far:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
  ID AS '@id'
  ,1 AS '@version'
  ,'en' AS '@lang'
  ,'Joe Smith' AS 'field/Name'
  ,'email@add.com' AS 'field/Email' 
FROM Table
FOR XML PATH ('add')
```

The XML format it returns:

```
<add id="123" version="1" lang="en">
  <field>
    <Name>Joe Smith</Name>
    <Email>email@add.com</Email>
  </field>
</add>
```

How I need it to return:

```
<add id="123" version="1" lang="en">
  <field name="Name">Joe Smith</field>
  <field name="Email">email@add.com</field>
</add>
```

How do I do this, so far that's the furthest I got with the documentation I found online.. Please help.

Comment: This does it for one but the problem is cannot use it for two as cannot repeat a column name  ,'fieldName' as 'field/@name', [table].[colX] as 'field'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)

```
SELECT TOP 1 
  ID AS '@id'
  ,1 AS '@version'
  ,'en' AS '@lang'
  ,(
    SELECT  x.Attribute AS  '@name',
            x.Value     AS  'text()'
    FROM    (VALUES (N'Name', N'Joe Smith'), (N'Email', N'email@add.com')) x(Attribute,Value)
    FOR XML PATH('field'), TYPE
  )
FROM (SELECT 1 ID) AS Table1
FOR XML PATH ('add')
```

2) Second solution uses a *template* and variables. I propose this solution because i saw `TOP 1` (maximum one row). First you should transfer the values from that row into variables (`SELECT @Variable = Column, ... FROM Table`). You have greater flexibility but the performance **could be** affected (note: I didn't do any tests).

```
DECLARE 
    @ID INT = 1,
    @Version INT = 1,
    @Lang NVARCHAR(10) = N'en',
    @Name NVARCHAR(50) = N'Joe Smith',
    @Email NVARCHAR(100) = N'email@add.com'

DECLARE @x XML = N'';
SELECT @x.query(N'
<add id="{sql:variable("@ID")}" version="{sql:variable("@Version")}" lang="{sql:variable("@Lang")}">
  <field name="Name">{sql:variable("@Name")}</field>
  <field name="Email">{sql:variable("@Email")}</field>
</add>
');
```

Comment: Thanks, but for your second solution, would I need to set up a cursor or something to go through each row if the result is not only 1 row? (`TOP 1`)

Comment: @ZeeTee: If you have many rows (not `TOP 1`) then the second script isn't a solution. Use instead the first solution.